# Restrict the choice of radio button by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form in which the pair of radio buttons are located, and the names of each pair are the same. How to limit the number of choices.
See the image below

[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvDwG.png)

How do I make sure the user is finally able to select 3 rows and no more?

this html code

```
<div class="bread-scroll-box" style="">
    @foreach ($additives as $additive)
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between hover-bg-gray trs p-3">
            <div class="make-cake-img">
                <img src="{{ $additive->icon }}" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="bread-title w-100 pr-3">
                <p class="text-12 weight-800 mb-0">{{ $additive->title }}</p>
                <small class="text-gray">{{ $additive->description }}</small>
            </div>
            <div class="bread-check w-25">
                <label class="x-checkbox-no-bg">select
                    <input type="radio" name="checkbox{{ $additive->id }}" class="right-select" data-weight="{{ round(($additive->weight / 2) * $tray->ratio) }}" data-price="{{ $additive->price }}" data-img="{{ $additive->halfImgUrl }}" data-id="{{ $additive->id }}">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="bread-check w-25">
                <label class="x-checkbox-no-bg">double
                    <input type="radio" name="checkbox{{ $additive->id }}" class="right-select" data-weight="{{ round(($additive->weight / 2) * $tray->ratio) }}" data-price="{{ $additive->price }}" data-img="{{ $additive->doubleHalfImgUrl }}" data-id="{{ $additive->id }}">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: @hasan-iman  i added the code, what your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From javascript, you can add event listeners on all radios and once the user selects 3 you disable the other controls.

If they unselect some and have < 3 selected you enable them again.

[Attach event listener through javascript to radio button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922002/attach-event-listener-through-javascript-to-radio-button)